# In Kill Team, can a Genestealer Cult team have a genestealer?

Tags: untagged

I'm new to **Kill Team** and got the starter box. Looking through my old bitz box, I found a few genestealers which I thought *"Perfect! I will add them to my genestealer cult."*

But looking through the Kill Team book, I can be sure if I can use those genestealer in my force or if I have to use them as proxy for something else.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes you can

In the Kill Team book, just above the entries for the Genestealer cults, there is a one-liner that explicitly states it.

Odd location, I would've preferred to have the Genestealer entry to have the Genestealer Cult Faction Keyword.